# how can I create students marks database?

Tags: sql-server-2008, ms-access-2007

I am trying to build a database (access)for students marks. Every student has many courses and different marks for each course.
Example
John:

### Math Q1 = 80, Q2= 90, Q3=77

Art
Q1=75, Q2=85, Q3=80

and so on
I build 3 tables with relations as the following
students(id-name-grade)
courses(courseid-coursename)
marks(id-courseid-Q1-Q2-Q3)

Is my work correct? because I will upgrade it to SQL, so I need to know if the tables and relations are identical for reports and forms?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, but you should rename some fields: courses(id, name), marks(stu_id, course_id, Q1, Q2, Q3)

SQL (I use PostgreSQL, but I think other DBMS similar)

```
CREATE TABLE students
(
id integer NOT NULL,
fname varchar(20),
lname varchar(20),
grade integer,
PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE courses
(
id integer NOT NULL,
name varchar(20),
PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE marks
(
stu_id integer REFERENCES students(id),
course_id integer REFERENCES courses(id),
Q1 double,
Q2 double,
Q3 double,
PRIMARY KEY (stu_id, course_id)
);
```

**or**

```
CREATE TABLE marks
(
id integer NOT NULL,
stu_id integer REFERENCES students(id),
course_id integer REFERENCES courses(id),
Q1 double,
Q2 double,
Q3 double,
PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

---

Hope your help

Answer (score 0):

You should use composite key in marks table. That will not limited you to only 3 questions.

Ms Sql Query for your table creation will look like-

```
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[students]    Script Date: 11/11/2014 16:20:05 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[students](
    [id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [fname] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [lname] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [grade] [int] NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,  ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO




/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[courses]    Script Date: 11/11/2014 16:19:59 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[courses](
    [id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [name] [varchar](20) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,  ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO



/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[marks]    Script Date: 11/11/2014 16:19:37 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[marks](
    [stu_id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [course_id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [q_id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [mark] [numeric](18, 0) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_marks] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [stu_id] ASC,
    [course_id] ASC,
    [q_id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,     ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[marks]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_marks_courses] FOREIGN     KEY([course_id])
REFERENCES [dbo].[courses] ([id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[marks] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_marks_courses]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[marks]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_marks_students] FOREIGN     KEY([stu_id])
REFERENCES [dbo].[students] ([id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[marks] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_marks_students]
GO
```